# Geocortex Viewer: Running a Workflow with Arguments

Tags: javascript, api, silverlight, geocortex

I have a webpage with the Silverlight Geocortex Viewer embedded in it.

Through the browser's developer console, I can run commands through it such as

```
silverlightPlugin.Content.essentialsViewer.RunCommand("RunWorkflow", "demo1");
```

However, I can't figure out how to run a workflow that has arguments. There's another command called "RunWorkflowWithArguments". Doing the following doesn't produce any results:

```
silverlightPlugin.Content.essentialsViewer.RunCommand("RunWorkflowWithArguments", {"workflowId":"demo2", "my_string":"test", "my_int":3} );
```

The developer manual said:

Parameter:
An object with the following properties: workflowId, and a
named property for each workflow argument.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Given a URL like this

http://[Server]/SL/Viewer.html?Viewer=[ViewerName]&runWorkflow=[WorkFlowName]&value1=1&value2=2

where [] values need to be fixed :)

In the [Workflow]  add two Variables
  urlValue string
  queryStringList NameValueCollection (When you set the variable type you need to browse for types)

Then add an activity GetBrowserUrl setting the Url and Query String Out Arguments

When this runs queryStringList will now have two entries

queryStringList.Item("value1") and queryStringList.Item("value2")